How Do You Configure azd Azure Aspire Endpoint Generation?
I am learning Aspire and am deploying to Azure via azd.  Everything is working well except for the endpoints being used for my application.  They are in the form of:
https://<project>--<randomcharacters>.kindplant-<more_random>.eastus2.azurecontainerapps.io
I am not sure about the more_random in the above.  The characters are random but appear to be more stable than the referenced randomcharacters which are generated every time a deployment is made.
I would like to "pin" the name of this endpoint so that it never changes.  I would like to think that this is configurable somehow, but I could not find it after searching.
Is it possible to configure the endpoints and keep them pinned to a consistent value between deployments?  Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

We're going to fix this to show the stable URL. Currently it's showing the revision url which changes every deployment.

Thank you for the clarification.  As I started to get more familiar with all the pieces I had noticed this.  The URL to use in the meantime is generated and emitted during azd deploy.
